# How to determine fortnight number from date

Tags: c#, date

I have a niggling problem that I am having trouble conceptualising a solution.

I have a payroll system that has the following rules:

1. The Pay period relating to each pay period is 14 days long starting 
   on Monday and ending on Sunday
2. Payday is each fortnight on Thursday following the last day of the pay period.
3. Pay periods are numbered 1 through to 26 (or 27 in some years) with ONE being the first payday in the financial year and 26 (or 27) being the last in the financial year.
4. Our financial year runs July 1 to June 30

A known pay fortnight was started on 25/06/2012 and ended on 8/07/2012.  The pay day for this period was 12/07/2012.  So I do have a few start points.

From any date, I can calculate what its pay date is because I have a known start point. I can also calculate the financial year it relates to easily enough.  There are many solutions to those problems on SO.

I now need to allow my users to enter a date and have the application show the pay period it relates to.

What I am struggling with is how can I determine which pay period (1 to 26/27) it is in the financial year?  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the yearBegin always start on July 1st?

Comment: The financial year always starts on July 1

Comment: So you never would have just 26 periods, always 27.

Comment: No, you can absolutely have 27 periods.
An example is pay period 13/6/2022 to 26/06/2022.  Because the pay day is 30/6/2022 it is the 27th pay period of that year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your user enters a date, and you can calculate its pay date, right? Let "payDate" be this pay date, and what you want is "which fortnight of the financial year does payDate fall in, numbered starting with one", right?

Then, you first need to determine the beginning of the financial year:

```
DateTime yearBegin;
if (payDate.Month >= 7)
  yearBegin = new DateTime(payDate.Year, 7, 1);
else
  yearBegin = new DateTime(payDate.Year - 1, 7, 1);
```

With this you can calculate how many days are there between payDate and yearBegin:

```
int delta = (payDate - yearBegin).Days;
```

Finally you get the answer:

```
int period = (delta / 14) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the first pay day from any given year starts at a different day to always match full periods of 14 days. If that is the case, you could try this code:

```
static DateTime InitialDate = new DateTime(2012, 06, 25);
private static int PayPeriod(DateTime inputDate)
{
    int periodStartDay = (inputDate - InitialDate).Days % 14 + 1;
    int periodStartMonth = 07;
    int periodStartYear = inputDate.Month >= 7 ? inputDate.Year : inputDate.Year - 1;
    DateTime periodStartDate = new DateTime(periodStartYear, periodStartMonth, periodStartDay);
    int payPeriod = (inputDate - periodStartDate).Days / 14 + 1;
    return payPeriod;
}
```